# Error from excel - list of lists - how do I fix?

Tags: xml, grouping

I'm trying to create an xml map for a set of data that has multiple lines for the same account number.
I get an error in excel that it is not able to export because it contains lists of lists. How can I correct this?

I've tried everything I can think of.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<utilbills-lien xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<record>
  <bill>="19665">
    <bill_due_from>01-01-2000</bill_due_from>
    <bill_due_to>09/20/2018</bill_due_to>
    <parcel>100..0-4--1.-26</parcel>
    <cat>60</cat>
    <year>2017</year>
    <account>710</account>
    <name>Shelestovski, Egor &amp; Olga</name>
    <service_type>
      <service>SEWFLT</service>
      <service>SPEN</service>
      <service>WPEN</service>
    </service_type>
    <line_number>
      <line>1</line>
      <line>2</line>
      <line>3</line>
    </line_number>
    <service_description>
      <description>SEWERFLAT</description>
      <description>SPENALTY</description>
      <description>WPENALTY</description>
    </service_description>
    <service_location>720 Town Line Rd</service_location>
    <grp>CH</grp>
    <d>CH</d>
    <charge_amount>
      <charge>$70.22</charge>
      <charge>$5.31</charge>
      <charge>$5.68</charge>
    </charge_amount>
  </bill>="19665">
</record>

</utilbills-lien>
```

Comment: I get that. I was looking for more help on the logistics of the grouping than the form of the code itself.